# VBA: selecting an active word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I recently learned how to manipulate Word documents through VBA in Excel. My problem is I want my macro to be able to determine an active word document with a proper filename and select that document and continue the macro. I have this code below

```
Sub CreateNewWordFile()
  Dim wrd As Word.Application
  Dim Opfile As Object
  Dim AcFile As Object

  Set Opfile = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  Debug.Print Opfile.Documents.count
  For Each AcFile In Opfile.Documents
    If AcFile = "SampleWord " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".docx" Then
      Set wrd = AcFile.Application
      With wrd
       .Activate
       .Selection.TypeParagraph
       .Selection.TypeParagraph
       .Selection.Font.Size = 20
       .Selection.TypeText "success"
       .ActiveDocument.Save
       GoTo Label1
      End With
    End If
  Next
  Set wrd = New Word.Application

 With wrd
   .Visible = True
   .Activate
   .Documents.Add
   With .Selection
       .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
       .BoldRun
       .Font.Size = 18
       .TypeText "Sample Word File"
       .BoldRun
       .TypeParagraph
       .Font.Size = 12
       .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
       .TypeParagraph
       .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
       .Font.Size = 15
       .TypeText "samples"
   End With

  ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="Documents\SampleWord " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".docx"

  End With

Label1:

  Set Opfile = Nothing
  Set wrd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Below the `For Each` loop is my code for creating a Word document in case there is no open Word document with the proper filename. The problem is when the `For Each` Loop runs the macro it gives the error

> ActiveX component can't create Object

But when I turn it into a comment and just run my code that creates a Word document and uncomment it for my second run to test, it works. Also I notice that the `Documents.count` doesn't count the open Word documents. I tried opening several Word documents but it doesn't count them. I hope someone can help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give you a lot of information, but not change your code. You'll learn more if you can implement what I explain. Your main problem comes from not fully grasping what's happening when you use `GetObject` vs. `New Word.Application`. Once you get that sorted you should be OK.

If Word is not running at all, then `GetObject` returns the error message you're seeing. The typical way to handle that is to test the error and start Word, if necessary, for example

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If err.number = 429 Then
    Set wrd = new Word.Application
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

HOWEVER, since you're looking for a specific document, as long as that document has been saved and you know the file path, you could (but don't have to) use

```
Dim wrdDoc as Object
Set wrdDoc = GetObject("C:\ExamplePath\DocName.docx")
Set wrd = wrdDoc.Application
```

It's also not necessary to loop the Documents collection to pick up a document with a certain name. You can also do:

```
Set acFile = wrd.Documents("Filename")
```

You can test whether that document exists using

```
If acFile Is Nothing Then
  'put the code to create a new DOCUMENT here
  Set acFile = wrd.Documents.Add
  'Do all the formatting, etc. here
End If
```

The main problem with `Documents.Count` comes from using

```
Set wrd = New Word.Application
```

every time the code doesn't find the specific document. This creates a *new instance* of Word every time it executes. Each instance is independent of any others, which is why `Documents.Count` doesn't return a number equal to all the documents you've generated. It is only running for the current instance of Word.